# How to echo a table for addressbook in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, echo

I'm trying to build a addressbook in PHP but I'm stuck at a point. How can I echo a table that automaticaly add a table row to display the next user in the addresbook, and how can I display all the users in my addressbook in the same table?

This is the code I have now.I hope someone can help me

```html
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

include "connect.php";

if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] !== true || !isset($_SESSION['userid']) || $_SESSION['userid'] == "") {
 header('location: login.php');
 exit();
// Natuurlijk wel even controleren of de user daadwerkelijk is ingelogd!
// Als de login niet bestaat, terugsturen naar de homepage. Tevens script stoppen met uitvoeren voor de extra veiligheid.
} else {
 session_regenerate_id();
 // sessio_regenerate_id moet je altijd gebruiken wanneer de autorisatie van een gebruiker veranderd.
 // Dit is tegen de hack session fixation, waarbij een hacker meelift op de sessie van een ander.


 $userQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT roepnaam, telefoon, naam, bedrijf, stad, straat1, straat2, provincie, postcode, email FROM address");
 // $userid is een integer (getal), en deze zet je in SQL niet tussen quotes.
 // Tevens hoeft dit niet geHEX't te worden gezien deze informatie schoon uit de database komt
 $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery);
 // Haal de gegevens uit de database als een associative array
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:60%">
  <tr>
    <th>Roepnaam</th>
    <th>Naam</th>
    <th>Bedrijf</th>
    <th>Telefoon</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Straatnaam 1</th>
    <th>Straatnaam 2</th>
    <th>Postcode</th>
    <th>Stad</th>
    <th>Provincie</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $user['roepnaam']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user['naam']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user['bedrijf']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your $conn is included in the script.
If the connection is correct. 
Remove previous $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery); 
and do this:

```
<?php
while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$user['roepnaam']?></td>
    <td><?=$user['naam']?></td>
    <td><?=$user['bedrijf']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
<?php
while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $user['roepnaam']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user['naam']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user['bedrijf']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

for more detail have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: It doesn't work, If i use this in my code it doesn't echo anything. Changed it in the code. You can see it at the top of this page

Comment: remove `$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery);` from your else block